# Search event in facebook - required user access_token

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, access-token

My app is looking for events in facebook in a particular city by https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Sity&type=event&access_token=[..] and publishes the data found on another site.
To search for public events in the marker is now required Facebook access token.

How can I get a long token that my application was looking for events without requiring additional permissions to users?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Get an app access token – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/

Comment: Access token obtained by reference does not allow to obtain the necessary data. For example, here access token that gets my application access_token = 454894834534166|_eEzPgWNhZhSrhEgjpln-F7l4v4

At https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=conference&type=event&access_token=454894834534166|_eEzPgWNhZhSrhEgjpln-F7l4v4 no events are returned.But at the address indicated on the http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ data is returned.

Comment: If you want to do your queries with a user access token, then you’ll have to get it from the user, and have it renewed by him regularly – there is no way around that.

How to handle these cases is described on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/access-token-expiration/ and https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/